# Paramiko randomly takes 30+ seconds to import

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

The issue is that paramiko will take 30+ seconds to import. This happens "randomly" from the testing that I've done so far. I run the script, and it just freezes for 30-60 seconds, then eventually will continue with the code. I ran it in debug, and it gets to the paramiko import, and will not move to the next (n) line in the code.

At first I thought it might be that my ssh sessions are not closing properly, but I don't think that's the case. The ssh session is definitely closed according to netstat, and this can happen after hours of no use on the host.

Here is the pertinent information:

- I have about 5 python scripts that import paramiko, and they all have this issue.
- Sometimes I can run these scripts 10 times (even simultaneously) without issue, then suddenly none of the scripts will import paramiko during the time it's un-import-able, all the scripts just freeze at the import (which is always near the top of my script).
- Other times I wake up in the morning, the host that runs these scripts has been untouched for 12 hours, and the first time I run one of the scripts, it takes 60 seconds to import paramiko.
- This happens on production hosts (CentOS 7.5.1804) and lab hosts (CentOS 7.4.1708)
- This happens on paramiko versions 2.2.1, 2.4.1, and 2.4.2.

I had to strip like 50 lines from this code, but this is essentially the code that uses paramiko. Keep in mind that this is used in 5 different scripts, so the rest of the code is completely different on all of them.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.modules['gssapi'] = None
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    ssh.connect(osHost, username='root', password=osPassw, port=22)
except paramiko.SSHException:
    print "Connection to OS CLI Failed. Probably wrong password." + osHost
    quit()
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
commandOut = stdout.readlines()
print commandOut
ssh.close()
```